# не пробрасывается порт на Mikrotik

Tags: сеть, mikrotik, portforwarding

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется роутер `Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD` стоит цель пробросить несколько tcp и udp портов.

По [этой](https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=mikrotik-port-forward) инструкции вбил все данные, но доступа нема. В чем причина, понять не могу...

Создал правило с такими параметрами:

[image: general]

[image: action]

Подключался c компьютера **вне** локальной сети

Внутренний ip верный,
внешний (белый) тоже

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался проще некуда
Я просто нашел другой гайд, и, оказывается, я просто не всё что надо указал, а ещё указал то что не надо

1. У меня **1** внешний ip поэтому можно было не указывать `Dst. Address`
2. В `Dst. Port` нужно указать только тот порт который будем слушать, ибо во вкладке `Action` нужно будет указать `To Ports` *(который я не указал)* а он будет либо один, либо диапазоном *(а не 2 порта как я хотел)*
3. Головой я своей думать, видимо, не умею, по этому указать в какой порт микротика у меня приходит интернет я не догадался *(во вкладке `General` нужно было указать `In. Interface`)*

Итог получился таким:

[image: General]

[image: Action]